# What is the most popular website written in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to justify writing a website in asp.net that has the potential to be as large as wikipedia. Are there any large websites content driven websites that have been written asp.net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: on http://www.alexa.com/topsites , Windows Live asp.net is upper than wikipedia, also MSN site, Microsoft site, MSDN site and many other on asp.net are.

Comment: @Aristos, all those sites are self-made, any example of an external company using ASP.NET? (Ebay, Amazon, Google, Facebook - something that big - not from MSFT itself)??

Answer (score 2):

From what i've heard ...

- Stackoverflow
- PlentyOfFish
- Myspace (once was based on coldfusion)